# ng-switch not working for me

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I cannot understand why ng-switch is not working for me. Seems that I did everything like it should be.

DIVs with ng-switch directive are not showing. Most likely I put wrong value in ng-switch-when, but I cannot undertand how to fix it.

[Here is my code](http://codepen.io/schel4ok/pen/jrrmre)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Размер дверной коробки
        <div class='input' ng-repeat="a in sizeswitch">
            <input type="radio" name='radio' ng-model="$parent.selectedSizeSwitch" ng-value="a.desc" id="@{{a.value}}">
            <label for="{{a.value}}">{{a.label}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div ng-switch on="$parent.selectedSizeSwitch">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-switch-when="Стандартный">Стандартные размеры дверной коробки (мм)
        <div class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white">
            <select ng-model="selectedStandardSize" ng-options="b.label for b in standardsizes" class="standard_sizes custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-switch-when="Ввести размер">Нестандартные размеры дверной коробки
        <div class='input'>
            <input name="door_size_b" id="input1" type="text" ng-model="DoorSizeB" placeholder=""><label for="door_size_b">Ширина дверной коробки, мм</label>
        </div>

        <div class='input'>
            <input name="door_size_h" id="input2" type="text" ><label for="door_size_h">Высота дверной коробки, мм</label>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>


</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Стекло</span>
        <div class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white">
            <select ng-model="selectedGlass" ng-options="c.label for c in glass" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Материал коробки</span>
        <div class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white">
            <select ng-model="selectedKorobka" ng-options="d.label for d in korobka" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Петли</span>
        <div class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white">
            <select ng-model="selectedPetli" ng-options="e.label for e in petli" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Декор</span>
        <div class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white">
            <select ng-model="selectedDekor" ng-options="f.label for f in dekor" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Доставка</span>
        <div class="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--white">
            <select ng-model="selectedDostavka" ng-options="g.label for g in dostavka" class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--white"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='input col-xs-12 col-sm-6'>
        <input type='checkbox' id='montazh' ng-model="montazh" ng-true-value="1500" ng-false-value="0"/>
        <label for="montazh">Монтаж</label>
    </div>
</div>


<table class="result table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"> 
    <caption>Итоговая спецификация</caption>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Опция</td>                          <td>Значение</td>                                               <td>Цена, руб</td></tr>
<tr><td>Размер дверной коробки (мм):</td>   <td>{{selectedSizeSwitch}}, {{selectedStandardSize.label}}</td> <td>{{selectedStandardSize.price}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Стекло</td>                         <td>{{selectedGlass.label}}</td>                                <td>{{selectedGlass.price}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Материал дверной коробки:</td>      <td>{{selectedKorobka.label}}</td>                              <td>{{selectedKorobka.price}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Петли:</td>                         <td>{{selectedPetli.label}}</td>                                <td>{{selectedPetli.price}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Декор:</td>                         <td>{{selectedDekor.label}}</td>                                <td>{{selectedDekor.price}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Доставка:</td>                      <td>{{selectedDostavka.label}}</td>                         <td>{{selectedDostavka.price}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Монтаж:</td>                        <td>{{montazh.label}}</td>                                      <td>{{montazh}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Стоимость двери:</td>               <td></td>                                                       <td>
    {{selectedStandardSize.price + selectedGlass.price + selectedKorobka.price + selectedPetli.price + selectedDekor.price + selectedDostavka.price + montazh}}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
        <label for="name">Ваше имя *</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="phone" name="tel" type="text"  required>
        <label for="phone">Номер телефона *</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email"  required>
        <label for="email">Адрес электронной почты *</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="input">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
        <label for="message">Комментарии</label>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="footer col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Отправить заказ</button>
</div>


</form>



angular
  .module('SaunaDoorCalc',[])
  .controller('SaunaDoorCalcController', function($scope) {

    $scope.sizeswitch = [           
      { label: 'Стандартный', value: 'standard', desc: 'Стандартный'},
      { label: 'Ввести размер', value: 'special', desc: 'Нестандартный'}
    ];
    $scope.selectedSizeSwitch = 'Стандартный'; // Default is Стандартный

    $scope.standardsizes = [           
      { label: '585х1880', price:5600 },
      { label: '685x1880', price:3600 },
      { label: '685x1980', price:5600 },
      { label: '685x2080', price:5600 },
      { label: '685x2180', price:6600 },
      { label: '785x1880', price:5600 },
      { label: '785x1980', price:5600 },
      { label: '785x2080', price:5600 },
      { label: '785x2180', price:6600 }
    ];
    $scope.selectedStandardSize = $scope.standardsizes[1];  
    // Default is 685x1880 - second array element. First element index is 0.

    $scope.glass = [           
      { label: 'Прозрачное (стандарт)', price:0 },
      { label: 'Матовое (Matelux)', price:1000 },
      { label: 'Бронза (Bronze)', price:1500 },
      { label: 'Матовая Бронза (Matelux Bronze)', price:2000 },
      { label: 'Черное', price:4000 }
    ];
    $scope.selectedGlass = $scope.glass[0]; 

    $scope.korobka = [           
      { label: 'Липа (стандарт)', price:1000 },
      { label: 'Лиственница', price:2000 },
      { label: 'Бук', price:3000 },
      { label: 'Дуб', price:6000 }
    ];
    $scope.selectedKorobka = $scope.korobka[0]; 

    $scope.petli = [           
      { label: 'Хром (стандарт)', price:900 },
      { label: 'Бронза', price:1900 },
      { label: 'Золото', price:2000 }
    ];
    $scope.selectedPetli = $scope.petli[0]; 

    $scope.dekor = [           
      { label: 'Нет', price:0 },
      { label: 'Пескоструйный рисунок', price:1000 },
      { label: 'Лазерная гравировка', price:1500 },
      { label: 'Фотопечать', price:2000 },
      { label: 'Пескоструйный рисунок с фьюзингом', price:3000 }
    ];
    $scope.selectedDekor = $scope.dekor[0]; 

    $scope.dostavka = [           
      { label: 'Нет', price:0 },
      { label: 'в пределах МКАД', price:1500 },
      { label: 'за МКАД', price:1500 }
    ];
    $scope.selectedDostavka = $scope.dostavka[0]; 
    $scope.montazh = 0;


    $scope.submit = function() {
      alert('submit');
    };



  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `$parent` use an object that is defined in the scope like this `$scope.outerScope`

```
 <input type="radio" name='radio' ng-model="outerScope.selectedSizeSwitch" 
           ng-value="a.desc" id="@{{a.value}}">
```

and in the controller initialize it to empty object

```
$scope.outerScope = {};
```

here is a working example http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/oLZbYo

you can also solve this by removing `$parent` from `<div ng-switch on="selectedSizeSwitch">`

the issue you are running into is the scoping of the ng-repeat, each item in the repeat is creating its own scope, this is why you need to use `$parent` there and not in the switch.

example of the second http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/YWZwLj

And for both you need to update `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-switch-when="Ввести размер">` to be  `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-switch-when="Нестандартный">`  it was looking for the wrong value.

Comment: thanks. This was not obvious for me. 
But now with this code value of  `ng-model="selectedStandardSize"` is not changing when I select different options.

Comment: the radio button should use  ng-model="$parent.selectedSizeSwitch" and <div ng-switch on="selectedSizeSwitch">.  Please reference the second working example if this is the option you would like to employee.

Comment: I suppose that you don't catch what I mean. Radio button works now. And ng-switch now switching divs like it supposed to do. But inside ng-switch I have div with ng-model="selectedStandardSize". In the bottom of form I have table showing current value of this model. And now it is not changing at all.

Comment: ok, so same issue.  the ng-switch has its own scope, use ```$parent.``` in the select not in the table.  I updated the codepen. http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/YWZwLj

Comment: If this solved your issue please accept the answer.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful. Issue is solved